# Button not sharing action between tabs

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I am using Onsen UI framework. I have an HTML app which contains 3 tabs (tab1, tab2 and tab3). All the code is under the same HTML file. In tab1, I have a button that when is checked the h2 changes colour. This change is made just on tab1 but I want the change in all of the three tabs.

Basically, this is the idea:

**HTML**

```
  <template id="tab1.html">
      <ons-page id="tab1">
        <!-- This is the button --> <ons-switch id="nightmode"></ons-switch>
      </ons-page id="tab1">
      <h2 class="title">Home</h2>
  </template id="tab1.html">

  <template id="tab2.html">
      <ons-page id="tab2">
          <h2 class="title">Home</h2><!-- It shall change colour, but it does not -->
      </ons-page id="tab2">
  </template id="tab2.html">

  <template id="tab3.html">
      <ons-page id="tab3">
       <h2 class="title">Home</h2><!-- It shall change colour, but it does not -->
      </ons-page id="tab3">
 </template id="tab3.html">
```

**JS**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("nightmode").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("nightmode").checked == true) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: white;");

  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: black;");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your backend code that changes colour of h2.

Comment: @sh4dowb Done, I should do it at first stage, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: black;");
```

This code changes first element only, because of `[0]`. You can change all elements with this code;

```
document.getElementById("nightmode").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

  var textcolor = "white";
  if(document.getElementById("nightmode").checked)
     textcolor = "black";

  for(var i in elms){
     var elm = elms[i];
     elm.style.color = textcolor;
  }
});
```

Also, I suggest using jQuery. With jQuery, it can be easier;

```
$("#nightmode").change(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $("h2.title").css("color", "white");
    else
        $("h2.title").css("color", "black");
}
```

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks. What shall I do using my function? Just change the [0]?

Comment: You must get all elements, loop through them, and change their color. Or for a dirty fix, you can copy&paste same line 3 times and make it [0] [1] [2]. It's not recommended though. Looping through all elements is the best way

Comment: I will try so, but I have to learn a bit more. Thanks so much!